# Typing component state with typescript when using react hooks

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

Class components in react take two interfaces namely for `props` and `state`

`Class MyComponent extends React.Component<IMyComponentProps, IMyComponentState> {}`

However while using hooks the component declaration looks like this

```
interface IMyComponentProps {
  ...
}

const MyComponent: React.FC<IMyComponentProps> = ({...}) => {
  const [state, setState] = useState(...);

  return (
    <>...</>
  );
};

export default FormMessage;
```

Is it necessary to specify interface for `state` while using hooks and how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can type your state, `useState` is a generic function

```js
const [state, setState] = useState<IMyComponentState>(...);
```